# Define variables with a variable name

Tags: shell-script, variable

What's wrong with this script?
I'm trying to define A1=1, B1=1, C1=1

```
LIST="A B C"
for x in $LIST
do
    "$x"1=1
done
```

and the result is:

```
./x.: line 7: A1=1: command not found
./x.: line 7: B1=1: command not found
./x.: line 7: C1=1: command not found
```

Comment: I don't think you can create variables in bash like this. This is what are the arrays for.

Comment: Use `eval "$x"1=1`. Although, as Jakuje noted, arrays are probably better suited for this case.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 22):

A variable assignment has the form of a variable name, followed by the equal sign, followed by the (optional) value.

This is a valid assignment:

```
ABC=123
```

`"$x"1=1` is not a valid assignment, because `"$x"1` is not a variable name. It may be *eval*uated to a variable name, but it isn't. The shell, in fact, believes it is a command.

One way for doing what you want to achieve is this:

```
eval "$x"1=1
```

Another way in bash (but not in other shells) is:

```
declare "$x"1=1
```

Or also (again bash-only):

```
let "$x"1=1
```

(There is no much difference in your case.)

But, as [Jakuje](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/121504/jakuje) noted in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224779/defining-symbols/224785#comment-381998), you probably want to go with arrays, if your shell has them (ksh, bash or zsh).

---

For completeness:

- `eval` executes arbitrary commands. So, if on the right side of the equal sign you have a variable that expands to some command, that command will be executed. The following code:

  ```
  x=a
  y='$(echo hello)'
  eval "$x=$y"
  ```

  is equivalent to `a=hello`.
- `declare` is a bash builtin to assign variables and won't execute any command. The following code:

  ```
  x=a
  y='$(echo hello)'
  declare "$x=$y"
  ```

  is equivalent to `a='$(echo hello)'`.
- `let` is similar to `declare`, in that it doesn't execute commands. But contrary to `declare`, `let` may be used for arithmetic operations:

  ```
  let a="1 + 2"
  ```

  is equivalent to `a=3`.

Comment: Even `ABC = 123` is invalid. Because space is added before and after the `equal(=)` sign.

Answer (score 3):

The bash FAQ has [an entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) on indirection.  In most use-cases, what you should actually do is use an associative or indexed array.  You can also use

```
func_call_by_reference() { # Bash 4.3
    typeset -n ref=$1   # nameref to the variable named by the caller
    ref=( "val1" "val2" ... )  # return an array by reference
}
```

See that FAQ entry for more options for doing this while still avoiding messy `eval` quoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like following. In your code shell executes `"$x"1=1` as a command because it not a valid variable assignment.

```
LIST="A B C"
for x in $LIST
do
    a=$(echo "$x"1)
    let $a=1
done
```

Comment: What shell are you using?  Using bosh bash 4.1.7 and 4.3.11 I get errors about `command not found <varname>=1` when I try to do that (obviously with <varname> being the value I stored in `a`)

Comment: as explained by @Andrea Corbellini , we have to use let, declare or eval to assign value..

Comment: you don't need `echo` here!  Just `a="$x"1`.  Also `let` is an arithmetic context, so you can only assign numbers with it.

Comment: `declare $a=foobar` works.